# Rails 3 - CanCan -Defining a Permission for Create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have the following in my controller for Attachment

```
  def upload

    @attachment = Attachment.build(:swf_uploaded_data => params[:attachment][:attachment], :user_id => current_user.id, :project_id => params[:space_id])
....
    end
```

What I'd like from CanCan is to only allow users to upload to a project_id they belong to. I confirmed the controller is getting the correct info, no nils

**Here is my cancan:**

```
can :upload, Attachment do |attachment|
  Rails.logger.info 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX- include CanCan::Ability - ATTACHMENT'  
  Rails.logger.info attachment.inspect
  Rails.logger.info attachment.project

  current_user.try(:role, attachment.space)
end
```

Problem here, is that attachment. is nil, and attachment.project is nil? How do you solve for this issue with CanCan so I can make sure only project teammembers can upload attachments to the project?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

I think the best approach it to do it at a lower level with the `authorize!` method that the Controller action.

So ...

```
#AttachmentController

#Will remove it from cancan
load_and_authorize_resource :except => [:upload]

def upload
 @attachment = Attachment.build(:swf_uploaded_data => params[:attachment][:attachment], :user_id => current_user.id, :project_id => params[:space_id])
  #add the authorize logic explicitly here when you have the attachment model populated
  authorize! :upload, @attachment
end
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

For example if you want to allow create events for current loop only:

You use in the view

```
link.... if can? :create, @loop.events.new
```

and then in controller

```
skip_authorize_resource only: [:new, :create]

...

def new
   @event.loop_id = @loop.id
   authorize! :create, @event
end

#similar for create action
```